# Raster Edge Identification

Tags: arcpy, python, raster

I am trying to create a script to create suitability indexes for various urbanized areas. I know that esri has a tool that does this but it doesnt perform the way we are looking to utilize it.

The issue is with the rasters. Some of the rasters are not squares but triangles. When you open a triangular raster in Numpy it is a square. I need a way to mask out the area that is added to the triangular area created from opening it in Numpy. The issue is the dead space is represented by 0 which is the same number class as water.

Below is an example of what i am talking about:

```
00000000000000000000000000000
00011111111111111100000000000
00011111111111111110000000000
01111111111111111000000000000
00000000111111111111111100000
00000000000111111000011111000
00000000000111111111111111000
00000000000000000000000000000
```

The zeros both represent the border and water.

Would someone know how to change this when importing in to Numpy?

Comment: What is your desired end product?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: we usually like to see the actual code that is causing the issue in as short a form as possible

Comment: @IanTurton so the code I have is follows

`arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster)`

my question deals more with if you have a triangular raster in a numpy array it will  be a square. I am looking for the best way to identify the area of the triangle that shouldn't be there so I can exclude it from the analysis.

Comment: please use the [edit] link to update your question

Comment: The raster is a rectangle in ArcGIS all rasters have to be, but the no data pixels are invisible. Whats the nodata value of the raster? `arcpy.Describe(r"C:\GIS\data\DEM50m\grid50m\nh_62_6.tif\Band_1").noDataValue` , isnt that value transferred to the numpy Array so it can be masked away or something?

Comment: @BERA I honestly didnt know you could grab the information that way. I am looking into it right now

Comment: @BERA It worked perfectly!!!!! I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raster is a rectangle in ArcGIS all rasters have to be, but the no data pixels are invisible.

Check the no data value of your raster:

```
arcpy.Describe(r"C:\GIS\data\DEM50m\grid50m\nh_62_6.tif\Band_1").noDataValue
```

Isnt that value transferred to the numpy Array so it can be masked away or something?

[image]